# Remove xA0 from powershell string

Tags: powershell

I see a few articles on removing the xA0 character from a string in Python, which I'm not unfamiliar with, however the tips there do not seem to work with Powershell.

My problem is that I'm parsing an excel file that somebody did a 'ctrl+space' and created an xA0 invisible character. I've removed it from the excel sheet, but I'm interested in knowing how to filter/remove out these characters in general.

It causes problems specifically when exporting these strings to XML (doesn't like those characters).

Answer (score 3):

If it is just the non-breaking space, you can use the `-replace` operator to replace it:

```
PS C:\> $s = [String]::Join([char]0x00a0, ('Hello','World'))
PS C:\> $s
Hello World
PS C:\> $s -replace [char]0x00a0,'-'
Hello-World
```

You might want to do the replacement after creating the XML:

```
PS C:\> ([PSObject]@{"name"=$s} | convertto-xml -as string) -replace [char]0xA0,'&#160;'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.Collections.Hashtable">
    <Property Name="Key" Type="System.String">name</Property>
    <Property Name="Value" Type="System.String">Hello&#160;World</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

Or a more complex replacement to handle any non-ascii characters:

```
PS C:\> $s = [string]::Join([char]160, ("Hello","Powershell","World", "♥♥♥"))
PS C:\> $myxml = $s | ConvertTo-Xml -as String
PS C:\> ([regex]"[\u0080-\uffff]").Replace($myxml, { param($m) "&#$([int][char]$m.Value);" })
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.String">Hello&#160;Powershell&#160;World&#160;&#9829;&#9829;&#9829;</Object>
</Objects>
PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the numeric value (in this case `0xA0` or `160`) and cast it as a `char`

```
# Here is our HTML string
$nbspString = "Hello","World!"-join$([char]0xA0)

# Here we replace the non-breaking space character with a regular space (0x20 or 32)
$normalizedString = $nbspString.Replace([char]0xA0,[char]0x20)

# Same thing, just using the `-replace` operator instead
$normalizedString = $nbspString -replace [char]0xA0,[char]0x20
```